# Printing in order

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that is a storyline but I want to put it in a certain order.

```
Outside = ["You look around for something to help you", "You remember the toolbox in the back of the plane", "You go to the back of the plane, and open the stairwell", "You open the back and see the toolbox"]


for Outside in Outside:
  print(Outside)
  time.sleep(3)


#Outside------------------------------------------------------

Inside = ["you sit inside this plane all alone", "A gentle breeze rustles the wheat around you"]

for Inside in Inside:
  print(Inside)
  time.sleep(3)

#Inside-------------------------------------------------------

Landing = ["Landing gear out", "Touchdown"]

Exitplane = input("\nDo you want to exit the plane: ")
if Exitplane == ("y"):
  print("You hop onto the ground" + Outside) 
if Exitplane == ("n"):
  print(Inside)
#Endcode-------------------------------
```

As you can see above that is the code I want to run but I want to run the Landing section first then run either Inside or outside (depending on user input)

Thank you for your time

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  “Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
You seem to be asking for individual tutorial help in `input`, `if`, and functions.  This is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: No no this is how to put things in order like running things in a different order such as 1 3 2 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list with the str-values you have created:

```
story = [Outside, Inside, Landing]
```

Then you can print the values, as their values are stored in order in the list. If you have two sets of strings in each part of the story this should work:

```
for i, j story:
    print(i, j)
```

I'm not sure as to how to print the different parts of the stories if they have different numbers of strings. This is because the "i, j" part of the for-loop prints the first two string of the list of strings. You could drop the commas between the different sentences in "Outside, Inside and Landing", whereas you could simply print it normally:

```
for i in list:
    print(i)
```